# Expres. JS Same client, Multiple Request, Blocking next one

Tags: express, concurrency, nonblocking

Was facing this issue with php. If i try to make multiple request to express server which takes 3-5 seconds to run with same browser, It block  next one.

There is no problem when i try with incognito mode or other clients( like Android in same wifi )

I want to solve this issue by making express to allow multiple connections/ request from same client, Same browser same time